# How to do programmatically launch multiply instances of some app on android

Tags: android

I just want to know is it possible to launch multiply instances of some app (Chrome for example) programmatically?
I just know that it is possible to clone some app manually and run it twice like two different apps.

Comment: Read this [Android Developer topic](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) under `android:launchMode`. That is dependent on how the App is declared in the Manifest.

Comment: you mean Deeplinking?

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to know is it possible to launch multiply instances of some app (Chrome for example) programmatically?

No. There will be at most one copy of an app running at a time.

You *may* be able to start multiple instances of an *activity* from some other app, by calling `startActivity()` several times (see Vishwesh Jainkuniya's answer). That may not even work, as manifest settings on the other app may route all of those calls to a single activity instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by

```
Intent browerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("www.google.com"));
                        context.startActivity(browerIntent);
                        context.startActivity(browerIntent);
                        context.startActivity(browerIntent);
```

this will start 3 browser